# How to replace a data from a file if already exists and write a new data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi all i write a code to write my last row of datagrid view to a file as follows

```
    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            List<string> lstContent = new List<string>();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if ((string)row.Cells[0].Value == "FileControl")
                {
                    lstContent.Add((string)row.Cells[1].Value);

                    string mydata = string.Join(",", lstContent.ToArray());

                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Append.FileName, true))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine();
                        sw.Write(mydata);
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }
```

But if i click multiple times on save this is writing that line multiple times what i need is if already that line exists in the file i have to replace that line with new line. Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your StreamWriter is explicitly using the file with append = true.  Change the second parameter of the constructor to false if you want to overwrite the file each time.  Docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx).  Quote:

> append
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> Determines
> whether data is to be appended to the
> file. If the file exists and append is
> false, the file is overwritten. If the
> file exists and append is true, the
> data is appended to the file.
> Otherwise, a new file is created.

Revised code:

```
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Append.FileName, false))
  {
      sw.WriteLine();
      sw.Write(mydata);
  }
```

Replacing **a given line** in your file rather than just overwriting the whole file is a lot more difficult - this code is not going to get it done.  `StreamWriter` is not great for this, you need random access and the ability to replace one data segment (line) by a different data segment of different length, which is an expensive operation on disk.

You might want to keep the files in memory as a container of `String`s and do your required line replacement within the container, then write out the file to disk using [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx) - that's if the file is not too big.

Comment: If i set it to false i am unable to find my first line in my text file only that last data row is displayed

Comment: @Dorababu - see edit - you are not going to be able to do this without more work and a restructure - StreamWriter is not the right class.